# Is it possible to invoke class methods, set/get properties from console or powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

If I write a class library in Visual Studio, is it possible to write a console application or powershell script which can call the methods or set/get the properties?

This is useful for testing APIs without having to create a form with loads of buttons etc.

I actually meant my executing my own class libraries. So if I write a class library with a namespace of a.b with a class called c and a method in c, called test(), I'd want to execute this from a console app or PS.

Thanks

Comment: While I'm all in favor of PowerShell, you may want to look at unit testing frameworks such as NUnit for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell makes it even easier than a console app, just open the PowerShell console and new up your object. You can then set properties, call methods, etc.

```
    $request = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("http://somewhere/")
    $request.Method = "Get"
    $request.KeepAlive = $true
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $response.Close()
```

I should be clear this is really most useful for doing spot checking or trying out a new API. In most cases using some kind of unit testing framework (MSTest, NUnit, etc), as others have mentioned, will give you better return on your time investment.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do from a Console Application -

Just add a reference to your class library, and use the types as needed.  Just be aware you'll only be able to access your **public** API, since it's a separate assembly.

However, for testing purposes, you might want to consider using a testing framework.  Visual Studio includes one (in Pro+ SKUs).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Powershell, You can use IronPython:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("MyLibrary");

foo = MyNamespace.MyClass()
foo.Property = "something"
print foo.GetSomeValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Powershell is able to call methods and set properties of .Net classes directly.

```
$conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connstr)
$conn.Open()
$comm = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()
$comm.Connection = $conn
$comm.CommandText = $sqlstr
$dr = $comm.ExecuteReader()
while($dr.Read())
{
   //...
}
$dr.Close()
$conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write an application that calls methods from a library.